# Issue: email based google form responses

Tags: javascript

I found part of the answer I was looking for. Here is my updated question: On form submit, generate a customized email based on answers provided in the form. The issue I have is that the current code does not provide the data found on the last row. The email I receive has data from the right sheet, the right column, but the wrong row. I want the data related to the last row (last form submit). How do I do this?

```
function sendEmail(range) {
Logger.log("[METHOD] sendEmail");


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('THIS SHEET HAS THE DATA I WANT');   
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
var row = values[0];

var Name = row[1];
var teacherEmail = row[2];
var principalEmail = row[3];
var riskType = row[13];
var riskTodo = row[14];

var emailRecipients = "franzplangger@gmail.com";
var emailSubject = "Trip plan submitted by "+teacherEmail+"";
var emailBody = "This is static text that gets pre-filled, the text below is taken directly from the google sheet (and based on what the teacher clicks)<p>\
<h3 style='line-height:90%'> These are the hazards: "+riskType+"<br /> <br>(These are the defenses "+riskTodo+")";

// SEND EMAIL //
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emailRecipients,
subject: emailSubject,
htmlBody: emailBody
});
}
```

This is the link to the form: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUPTkTtJkPA9hEdrb7TM-VOzy6_-ib0Qg9-KZezAgPQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you specify what's not working? Is the problem persisting data after sending the email, or generating the email in the first place?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't provide us with useful information.  Please elaborate on *how* it doesn't work.  Are you getting an error?  What is the expected behavior and what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my question (with the help of a programmer or two). I am posting the answer here in case it helps somebody else. I had 3 needs.

First: I needed to get the email data from a specific sheet (form answers needed some calculations done on a separate sheet).

Second, I needed to find the last row of that sheet.

Third: because my calculations on the 2nd sheet were repeated in all cells (to automate process when new form is answered), I needed to identify the last row as a string (visible text in cell) as opposed to the value within the cell (background formula in most of the cells were seen as the cell having a value and not being empty).

Here is the code:

```
function sendEmail(range) {

     //Get values in last row of sheet (sheet has a repeating formula in background.
     // This requires more code to identify last row with 
     // written content as opposed to last row with formula in it)
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname'); //this goes
                                             //to the specific sheet I want the data from  
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var column_2_Data;
    column_2_Data = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    column_2_Data = column_2_Data.toString();//this converts column 2 to string
    column_2_Data = column_2_Data.split(",");//this converts to a 1D array
        //I chose column 2 because this column did not have a formula in it. 
        //It ended at the same row as the last form submission.  

 var lastRowOfData = column_2_Data.indexOf("");//this gets the index of the empty element 
                                              //(the position of the empty row)
 var lastRow = lastRowOfData - 1; //data is zero indexed - subtract 1

      //code to link customized portion of the email with specific columns in sheet
 var row = values[lastRow];
 var name = row[1];
 var personXEmail = row[2];
 var bossEmail = row[3];
 var riskType = row[13];
 var riskTodo = row[14];

      //email content
 var emailRecipients = ""+bossEmail+"";
 var emailSubject = "Trip plan submitted by "+personXEmail+"";
 var emailBody = "This is static text that gets pre-filled, the text below is taken directly from the google sheet (and based on what the person clicks)<p>\
                  <h3 style='line-height:90%'> These are the hazards: "+riskType+"<br /> <br>(These are the defenses "+riskTodo+")";

     // SEND EMAIL
 MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: emailRecipients,
 subject: emailSubject,
 htmlBody: emailBody
});
}
```

If you only need to get data from the last row of a sheet that does not have repeating formulas in it, you can use this simpler code.

```
function sendEmail(range) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname');   
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var lastRow;
    lastRow = values.length - 1;//data is zero indexed - subtract 1
var row = values[lastRow];

     //the rest would be 
var name = row[1];
var personXEmail = row[2];
    //etc......
```

I hope this helps.